# Functional calculation for Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

First, let me recall some useful definitions

We recall that if $A=U \Lambda U^*$ is a Hermitian matrix with $U U^*=U^* U=I$ and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}\left(\lambda_1\right)$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function then the matrix $f(A)$ is defined by
$$
f(A)=U \operatorname{diag}\left(f\left(\lambda_i\right)\right) U^{*}
$$

If $f$ is further differentiable, then
$$
\operatorname{Tr} f(A+H)=\operatorname{Tr} f(A)+\operatorname{Tr}\left(f^{\prime}(A) H\right)+o(\|H\|), \quad H \in \mathcal{H}_n .
$$

**My problem**
Let $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous continuous functions with compact support. We consider the Hermitian matrices $f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ and $g\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$.

We will fix that $k\in [n]$ and $k \le l$. I want to identify constant $\alpha$ and $\beta$  such that

\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{k k}}\left\{\operatorname{Tr} f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right\}=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n}}\left[f^{\prime}\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]_{k k} \\
& \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{k \ell}}\left\{\operatorname{Tr} f\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right\}=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{n}}\left[f^{\prime}\left(\frac{X}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]_{\ell k}
\end{aligned}

I tried to take $H=X_{kk}$ and $H=X_{kl}$ and use the above formula but I can't obtain the result. Could you please help me with this problem?
Thank you very much for your help.